# How to make a braille interface for our website

Tags: html, css

I want to know how can I make a website design/interface for blind people.

in my CSS I should use:

```
@media braille {
    a {
        ????
    }
    ul,ol,li {
        ????
    }
    img {
        ????
    }
    ...
}
```

But How should I style my CSS so that my links, lists, images or any other tag ( or at least some of tags ) be comprehensible for blind people 
?

Can anybody help me.
thanks.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask things like that. This place is for specific implementation issues. Not for general question about how to get started with some technology.

Comment: it's not a technology. css @media offers braille so there should be a way to do that

Comment: Sure. So why don't you take a look into the documentation and examples then?

Comment: I have done that before, please, if you don't have enough knowledge to answer, have enough politeness and let others to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all: you need to understand [how blind people access computers](http://www.webbie.org.uk/webbie.htm).

@media braille is only a method to to target braille devices not a panacea to create an accessible interface for blind or visually impaired users. Instead, it allows you to reorganize layout (e.g. hide/show specific stuff) to make your interface more convenient. Also keep in mind that you should take into account screen readers.

Web accessibility is a huge topic to cover within a SO answer, but here are links that might give you some direction:

[Design Websites For Blind/Visually Impaired](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/design-website-for-blind/) (take a look at the links below this article as well)

[Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/)